# kafka metrics package (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics) documentation

Tags: apache-kafka

I run through some kafka code which uses classes from org.apache.kafka.common.metrics package.
i am not able to find the documentation of it in version of kafka.

where can i find the documentation of it.

Answer (score 0):

This package, `org.apache.kafka.common.metrics`, is not part of Kafka's public API. This is why there's no published javadocs. For the public APIs, see the [published javadocs](http://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/index.html).

Classes that are not part of the public API, such as the Metrics, can change at anytime and don't go through deprecation/compatibility cycles like public API classes do.

For that reason it's not recommended to build software that rely on private classes and if you do so, you have to handle possible breakage and use the source code for documentation.